# Why not working to write into a txt file with PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to write some simple text into a text file but writing is not working, Below is the code I am using: what is the wrong with the code please??

```
<?php
// create short variable names

$tireqty = 24;
$oilqty = 34;
$sparkqty = 12;


echo "<p>Your order is as follows: </p>";
echo $tireqty." tires<br />";
echo $oilqty." bottles of oil<br />";
echo $sparkqty." spark plugs<br />";


@ $fp=fopen("/order.txt","w");

   if(!$fp){
     echo "The file is not exists";

     exit;
     }

$outputstring = $date.'\t'.$tireqty.' tires \t'.$oilqty.' oil\t'
     .$sparkqty.' spark plugs\t\$'.$totalamount.'\t'. $address.'\n';



fwrite($fp, $outputstring);
fclose($fp);

echo "Order have written into order.txt";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please improve your question by posting all relevant **error messages** exactly as they appear. Also, make sure to include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` helps a lot for that :)

Comment: What is the result? Errors? Something?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to write a file to the root directory:

```
@ $fp=fopen("/order.txt","w");
```

The `/` indicates an absolute path. 99% of web servers won't have permission to write a file to the root folder, for security reasons. You should write the file to `/tmp` or some other directory that the web server has write access to.

```
$fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . "/order.txt","w");
```

This will write a file 'order.txt' to the same directory as the PHP script. `dirname` is getting the directory name of a file path, and `__FILE__` is a PHP constant that is equal to the absolute path of the current script. It might be equal to something like `/var/www/html/test.php`.

As of PHP 5.3.O the constant `__DIR__` is also available, which is equal to `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: `getcwd()` isn't easier?

Comment: `getcwd()` is not the same as `__FILE__`, the former returns the directory of the script that was called, while the latter returns the path of the file you are currently in.

Answer (score 0):

Place a dot(.) before slash (/) to mean current directory

```
$fp=fopen("./order.txt","w");
```

Also use double quote in

```
$outputstring = $date."\t".$tireqty." tires \t".$oilqty." oil\t"
 .$sparkqty." spark plugs\t\$".$totalamount."\t". $address."\n";
```

to get actual output. \t \n works as character in single quote